# VeeValidate errors is not defined when importing into custom plugin

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I'm building a custom Vue JS plugin using the `vue create` CLI. I've imported my various packages, however, I'm getting an error when trying to use custom settings with VeeValidate.

**plugin.js**

```
/*
 * NOTE:
 *   This file is plugin stub for main.js
 */

// Import required packages
import Vue from 'vue'
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

// Import custom LES form styling
import './assets/scss/les-application.scss'

// Import our plugin
import plugin from './index'

/* Vue Validation */
const config = {
  fieldsBagName: 'fields',
  errorBagName: 'errors',
  classes: true,
  strict: false,
  classNames: {
    valid: '',
    invalid: 'is-invalid'
  },
  events: 'change|blur',
  validity: false,
  inject: false,
  aria: true,
  delay: 0
}

Vue.use(require('vue-moment'))
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(VeeValidate, config)
Vue.use(plugin)

// Custom validation rules


/*
 * NOTE:
 *   If you want Vue instance of main.js to import something in your plugin as a Vue option,
 *   you need to export it here.
 */
// export default plugin
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './plugin'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

**Errors:**

```
Property or method "errors" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

and

```
Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
```

I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing from my configuration, if I remove the VeeValidate config from `plugin.js` it then uses the default VeeValidate options and is working.

Comment: Where's the code for the component that actually uses VeeValidate?

Comment: The code is within `/src/components/MyComponent.vue`

Comment: Right right, can we see the relevant code from `MyComponent.vue` then?

Comment: @RyanHolton i think it's because you disabled the automatic injection. You need to [request a new validator scope](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/concepts/injections.html#requesting-a-new-validator-scope) in every component where you need validations

Comment: @Sovalina How would I set this, I've read the docs, but am confused where that would go in my code snippets above

Answer (score 0):

It is the `inject: false,` in the validation config causing this. if you set this to true or do not set it, the errors object should be injected in your component without errors.

The `inject:false` stops automatic injections in vee-validate 2 http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/concepts/injections.html

This changes with vee-validate 3 where `ValidationObserver` and `ValidationProvider` need to be used https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/migration.html#migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0